# Why heart is on the left side?

Tags: organs

I am not a biologist

but I wonder if there is any benefit for the human to have hearts on the left side?

do animals have their hearts on the left too? or on the right?

Comment: Well, it's not... it's in the center, pointing to the left side: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60718/why-is-the-heart-not-in-the-middle-of-the-body https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5597/why-does-the-apex-of-the-human-heart-usually-point-to-the-left

Comment: There are humans with it on the right side. which side does not matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Is Most Life Symmetrical Externally But Not Internally?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/why-is-most-life-symmetrical-externally-but-not-internally)

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!